# Kabbalistic concepts taught in an allegorical story

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah

Looking for a book filled with stories (real or allegorical) which implicitly teach different Kabalistic concepts and how they're applied/relevant to different situations. Something like a Kabbalistic Midrash Aggadah.

Comment: Imo, Chassidus is the only place you'll find anything close to this. Chabad in particular has put out significantly more Kabbalistic explanations than other groups. On your last sentence, the Zohar is considered like a Midrash Aggadah, and is "Kabbalistic" in nature

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thank you, I know Chabad does a lot of good Kabbalah work, but I'm not sure if they ever made any of the concepts into a story-like format that explains them implicitly through different situations and contexts. I'll still see if they made anything though

Comment: Sounds like a Tomer Devorah with stories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rebbe Nachman's Stories](https://books.breslov.org/product/rebbe-nachmans-stories/) do precisely this. They're written with intention to give over Kabbalistic concepts, and R' Aryeh Kaplan's commentary culls together many significant commentaries who draw out many of those ideas very well. (Note: I know the website says the book is out of stock, but I also know they're in the process of reprinting, as well as putting together a new edition of the book, so keep checking back there. You can also look for it elsewhere, e.g. sefarim stores.)